# Is it possible to utilize the "Send mail as" Gmail feature from SMTP?

Tags: gmail, smtp, mac

I use Mail for Mac OSX Snow Leopard. I have my Gmail linked to non-Gmail email accounts so that I can send mail as them.

Is there a way to use this feature without the web interface (SMTP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edited, see comments]

In the Mail application you'll want to add a second (or third, etc. if you have more) SMTP account.  Then, when composing an email, you can select which account from which you wish to send it.  More information:

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20010401111133239

Comment: "Reply to" and "Send as" are two different features. "Send as" will show the email coming from a different address than it actually originated from. While "Reply to" will make it so when someone replies, by default it will go to a different address than the one shown in the "from" field of that email.

Comment: Ah, looks like you're right.  I guess I'm getting rusty :)  The steps in the Mail application should be the same, though.  More information: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20010401111133239

Comment: Might be worth adding in about the settings required to send over SMTP from Google... smtp.google.com, SSL, username & password (for the main Google account, not the new email address) for authentication.

Comment: Thankyou so much! this hint is going to save me a bunch of time.